# Automatically update a pie chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with lot of data, I create a pivot table to have a pie chart, I would like the pie chart to update if I filter on my sourcesheet data. I don't know if there's  way to automatically update the pie chart while filtering on the source sheet. For example if I created a pivot table with 10 elements and that I return in my source sheet and apply a new filter on 5 element I would like the pie chart to be updated automatically with the new filter without making a new pivot table

```
Sub Macro1 ()
    Cells.Select
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "Alarmes!R1C1:R1048576C11", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
            TableDestination:="Graphe DOS!R1C1", TableName:="Tableau croisé dynamique2" _
            , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
        Sheets("Graphe DOS").Select
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Graphe DOS'!$A$1:$C$18")
        With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Tranches")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
        End With
 'i'll be filtering on the SE column
        With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("SE")  
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1           
        End With
        With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Alarmes")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.AddDataField ActiveChart.PivotLayout. _
            PivotTable.PivotFields("Descriptifs"), "Nombre de Descriptifs", xlCount

 End Sub
```

Thank You for your time and help

Comment: Can you add screenshot of what you want? For me it is hard to understand as a filter in the raw data should not change the pivot table (or the chart attached to the table)

Comment: Do you mean *refreshing* the chart? If so, you could just refresh on every change with the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: i have this [pie](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19ghsAyfcv_xJmn_ItbMGY9r2FJ_pIy2H) chart  base on this [filter](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14au6fw4xH36Z44fUsXcwmyGWR7JLtxFm) and i want to refresh the pie chart while i add over component on the filter like this [newfilter](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c7-h6K0VYHgGI0EtB3XAawrXHDTjOfhX)

Comment: @Ibrahimatto if those are all pictures you're better off re-uploading them via the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51768614/edit) option as many people will not/cannot view those links

Comment: Ok I’ll try doing that. I’m not very familiar with stack Overflow yet.